# Woodstox stax empty characters

Tags: xml-parsing, stax, woodstox

i have an element like this

```
<name></name>
```

but in my switch statement

```
case XMLEvent.CHARACTERS:{
 ...
}
```

is not getting called. any idea how I can get this event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no character content to report, so you will not get CHARACTERS event. You will need to work around this; you can, for example, use `XMLStreamReader.getElementText()` when stream points to START_ELEMENT. Calling that method would return empty String in your case, and move stream to point to matching END_ELEMENT.